# Taking latitude and longitude coordinates and mapping them to a cartesian plane

Tags: c#

for a project I need what is described by the title. I have done a lot of digging, especially here on stack overflow but my use case is slightly different and I need some guidance or what I need to research.

I am placing objects on a 2D plane with x and y axis based on the user and object's latitude and longitude. The range and domain will be based on the max distance of the object from the user. For example, if I choose to show every object within a 60 mile radius, then the range and domain will be [-60, 60], with the origin being the user's coordinates.

Is there a name of a formula, method, or technique I can look into on how to do this? Is it simple and I am overlooking it?

Thanks for any and all help, I truly do appreciate it. If I am forgetting important information please don't hesitate to tell me.

Any research I've done either is inconclusive or doesn't help me with the coordinates and distances being limited and relative to the user.

Comment: And what is the problem on defining your coordinate-system? Just use longitde as x and latidude as y. That of course won't produce you a spheric presentation, though. This question has nothing to do with programming, it's about defining a coordinate-transformation.

Answer (score 1):

If your objects are within few kilometers (or miles), you can assume that your coordinates are in a 2D plane.
So you just have to get the min & max values for your coordinates, and for you result plane.

you will have :

```
x = lat * ((xmax - xmin) / (latMax - latMin)) + xOffset
y = lng * ((ymax - ymin) / (lngMax - lngMin)) + yOffset
```

Considering your example, your 2D plane is 120 width and height `xmin = -60 ; xmax = 60 ; ymin = -60 ; ymax = 60`

And the plane is centered arround 0, so `xOffset = 0 and yOffset = 0`.

You just have to extract the latitude and longitude max from your coordinates list.

You can also enlarge this limits to have a margin on your result plane :
Example with 5% :

```
latMin = latMin * 0.95
latMax = latMax * 1.05
```

If you really want to use the correct formula, you will have to project your coordinates into a 2D plan. To do this you will have to calculate a transform matrix and projection matrix.